# Evaluating $\lim_{t\to0} \tan(4t)/(2t)$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{t\to0} \tan(4t)/(2t)$$

How would I evaluate that. I know that the limit of tan(t)/t = 1. How do I get the 4t to become a 2t inside the tangent?

Comment: Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{t\to0} \tan(4t)/(2t)=2\lim_{4t\to0} \tan(4t)/(4t)=2$$

Comment: doesn't it seem like you would multiply by 1/2 though?

Comment: yes. you multiply by 1/2 to complete the calculation of the limit. you then multiply the result by 2 to get back to original question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\frac{\tan(4t)}{2t}=2\cdot \frac{\tan(\color{red}{4t})}{\color{red}{4t}}$$
and that $4t\to 0$ when $t\to 0$.